# Node.js: http request timing out after 1 minute

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, connection-timeout

I am using Node.js (version 0.10.28) to make an `http.request` to my Ruby API for a large amount of data (21,000 rows from a PostgreSQL database).  The problem is that the request seems to time out and return a 404 error after 1 minute.  I know this is true as the Ruby API returns 61 seconds for the request, and I time how long the Node's request takes (results in 60 seconds and the 404).  However, if I `wget` or use jQuery's `$.ajax` with a timeout of 4 minutes, I can get my 21,000 rows.  So clearly it can't be a 404, as other ways of getting the data work.

I'm a little confused too because everywhere I look, the `http.request` isn't supposed to time out until after 2 minutes, according to:

[Node.js docs](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_timeout)

[GitHub issue #1](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/3460)

[GitHub issue #2](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/4548)

I have tried several things to get this working, including: setting [express's middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21708208/express-js-response-timeout); [listening for the socket timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214902/how-to-set-a-timeout-on-a-http-request-in-node) and resuming the request; and setting the timeout to 0, so there's no timeout.  Unfortunately, none of these ways worked, or at least from what I've understood.

For some clarity, here's my code... setting that limit means return only 18,000 records, and that seems to be the cut off point for the API taking longer than 60 seconds:

```
var http = require('http');
var options = {
  path: '/api/records.json?limit=18000',
  method: 'GET',
  host: 'localhost',
  requestCert: true,
  rejectUnauthorized: false
};
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  var endDate = new Date();
  console.log('done', endDate - startDate);
  var output = [];
  res.on('data', function(chunk) {
    output.push(chunk);
  });
  res.on('end', function() {
    var data = output.join('');
    console.log(data);
    return {data: data, success: true};
  });
});
req.on('socket', function(socket) {
  socket.setTimeout(0);  // no timeout
  socket.on('timeout', function() {
    socket.resume();  // tried resuming the timeout
  });
});
req.end();
var startDate = new Date();
console.log('starting', startDate);
```

The API URL is valid and works, as I've verified that through `wget` and `$.ajax`, so how do I fix the timeout issue in Node?

**UPDATE**

Upon further inspection, if I take out `socket.setTimeout(0);` and try to get into the `socket.on('timeout'`, I don't actually get into the callback... which is odd, but it's always 60 seconds before I get the 404

Comment: Have you tried inspecting your traffic with Wireshark to make sure that Node isn't actually getting a response?

Comment: I'll see what I can do... I haven't used Wireshark in ages.

Comment: Also, it might be important to note that the documentation you linked to describes *server* timeouts for Node. The documentation pertaining to *request* timeouts is http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_settimeout_timeout_callback

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I've tried so many things that I just got lost in the documentation... I have tried `req.setTimeout(0);` but no dice.  I also thought I had read that `http` basically is `net`, which implements `server`.

Comment: Upon further inspection, if I take out `socket.setTimeout(0);` and try to get into the `socket.on('timeout'`, I don't... which is odd, but it's always 60 seconds before I get the 404.

Comment: A socket timeout wouldn't trigger a 404 response anyway, which is why I suggest you watch the actual request on the wire.

Comment: Right, I think the 404's the key, which I believe is an nginx setting that I need to change... trying it now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an nginx issue, as I'm using it to proxy through to my API, so it was a simple change of the proxy's configuration by setting `proxy_read_timeout 180s`.

Comment: You are a life saver. Indeed the default for [proxy_read_timeout](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_read_timeout) is 60 seconds. After that nginx will abruptly close the request regardless of whether NodeJS is done processing or not.

Answer (score 2):

As you said it's a nginx problem, but probably if you don't set in the nginx config the proxy parameters nginx default depends on the operative system, because in Ubuntu 16.04 I haven't any problem with a 10min timeout and without any proxy parameter, but in centos and redhat I saw the 1 min timeout restriction.

I add a configuration example because there are two parameters more than proxy_read_timeout that you need to set:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  myserver;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_connect_timeout      180s;
        proxy_send_timeout         180s;
        proxy_read_timeout         180s;

        proxy_buffer_size          4k;
        proxy_buffers              4 32k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
        proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
    }
}
```

For this issue the important parameters are:

```
proxy_connect_timeout      180s;
proxy_send_timeout         180s;
proxy_read_timeout         180s;
```

Answer (score 2):

Friends have had the same problem After working for 15 days, the source of the problem is "server.headersTimeout = 7200000;" you can fix it by adding this code