# How can I force a 504 error in chrome

Tags: node.js, http-status-code-504

How can I force a `504` error in Chrome?

We have a node app that we occasionally get a `504` error from and I wanted do some error handling for `504` errors.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214902/how-to-set-a-timeout-on-a-http-request-in-node maybe this could help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy this into a file called server.js then run `node server.js`. If you visit `http://localhost:8080` you will be thrown a 504 error.

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  console.log("Sending 504 error to client");
  res.writeHead(504, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end();
}).listen(8080);
console.log("Server started on port 8080");
```

Comment: Since I posted this I thought about building a web service to do this for any http status code. It turns out someone has already built it. http://httpbin.org It supports lots of different things but the status API does what you want. http://httpbin.org/status/504