# Wait x amount of time, then return if no response

Tags: node.js, http

I'm trying to test out a HTTP request with the `http` npm module. if the  request isn't sucessful it doesn't provide a response. I'm trying to make it so if there isn't a response in 3 seconds, it runs code such as `console.log('didnt work')`.

What i have:

```
http.get({
    path: 'http://google.com'
}, function (response) {
    if (!response) {
        console.log('didnt work')
    } else {
        console.log('worked')
    }

});
```

Comment: how is different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214902/how-to-set-a-timeout-on-a-http-request-in-node

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set a timeout on a http.request() in Node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214902/how-to-set-a-timeout-on-a-http-request-in-node)

Answer (score 0):

First, keep in mind that an http request is an asynchronous operation and the results whether a response or a timeout are event driven.  So, nothing here blocks until the response or timeout happens.  Instead, you register callbacks or listeners for events and you response to those.

More specifically, you can use the `timeout` feature for `http.get()`.  Doc [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_settimeout_timeout_callback).

```
request.setTimeout(timeout[, callback])

timeout <number> Milliseconds before a request times out.

callback <Function> Optional function to be called when a timeout occurs.
                    Same as binding to the 'timeout' event.

Returns: <http.ClientRequest>

Once a socket is assigned to this request and is connected 
`socket.setTimeout()` will be called.
```

If it sees no response within the timeout time you set, then it will generate the timeout event, call the callback and close down the socket.  You can use this as an event driven conclusion to the socket in the same way you might be waiting for the `data` event.