# How timeout works for http.get in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, http, https

I am using https.get to request send a GET request to an URL: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#httprequestoptions-callback

I am trying to figure out how the `timeout` option works.

Someone mentions that the `timeout` option strictly means connect timeout, and has no effect once the socket is established in this post: [How to set a timeout on a http.request() in Node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214902/how-to-set-a-timeout-on-a-http-request-in-node)

I have  simple getRequest function with retry logic. Besides the `timeout` option I also added a `setTimeout` function to handle issues after the socket is opened.

```
function getRequest(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const req = https.get(url, {timeout: 1000}, res => {
      let rawData = '';
      res.on('data', chunk => {
        rawData += chunk;
      });
      res.on('end', () => {
        resolve(rawData);
      });
    }).setTimeout(1000);
    req.on('error', err => {
      reject(new Error(err))
    })
    req.on('timeout', () => {
      req.end();
      getRequest(url);
    })
  });
}
```

I ran some tests, and out of 100 requests with this function, at least 1 takes exactly 5 seconds. That 5 seconds must be coming from somewhere, some default values, that I could not find.

How can I make sure that after 1 second the connection is closed and retry is initiated?

Edit: I tried all different kind of node modules with timeout capabilities: node-fetch, axios, etc. I face this issue using these modules as well. Axios throws the timeout error, but the node app itself does not finish, only after 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

this is an example:

```js
const https = require('https');

function getRequest(url, retries = 3) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const req = https.get(url, { timeout: 1000 }, res => {
      let rawData = '';
      res.on('data', chunk => {
        rawData += chunk;
      });
      res.on('end', () => {
        resolve(rawData);
      });
    }).setTimeout(1000);

    req.on('error', err => {
      if (retries > 0) {
        return resolve(getRequest(url, retries - 1));
      }
      reject(new Error(err));
    });

    req.on('timeout', () => {
      req.abort();
      if (retries > 0) {
        return resolve(getRequest(url, retries - 1));
      }
      reject(new Error('Request timeout'));
    });
  });
}

// Usage
getRequest('https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#httprequestoptions-callback')
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

Comment: I just tried, running this in loop with some delay in between. There are always some requests, which takes exactly 5 seconds.

Comment: we have Connection Timeout ({ timeout: 1000 } in the options) and Socket Timeout (setTimeout(1000) on the request)

Comment: I am not sure what other reason can be for some requests to take exactly 5 seconds.