# How do I set a socket connection timeout in node.js http client

Tags: http, node.js, socket.io

Is there a way to set a socket connection timeout in node.js http.request?

I'm not looking to set a http request timeout but a connection timeout.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586760/how-do-i-set-a-timeout-for-client-http-connections-in-node-js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set a timeout for client http connections in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586760/how-do-i-set-a-timeout-for-client-http-connections-in-node-js)

Answer (score 1):

Use `req.socket.setTimeout(30000);` This overrides the default of having no timeouts for sockets. Be aware that the `timeout` event will not automatically close the connection, you'll have to do that yourself when you handle the event, usually by calling `end()` or `destroy` on the socket. You can also add a one-time-callback as an optional parameter.